# How to iterate through a list of pointers to an object?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, linked-list, iterator

I have a `typedef` statement:

```cpp
typedef list <Event *> EventList;
```

which is on its own in my header file (not part of a class).

I have a function `nd_to_el()`, where I want to iterate through this `EventList`, which has already been filled with instances of `Event`.

This is what I tried:

```cpp
EventList::iterator it;

for (it = this->el.begin(); it != this->el.end(); ++it){
    cout << (*it)->key << endl;
}
```

(I am also not sure if dereferencing the iterator is correct here or not)

but I get this error:

```
error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘((CS302_Midi*)this)->CS302_Midi::el’, which is of pointer type ‘EventList*’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::list<Event*>*’} (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
for (it = this->el.begin(); it != this->el.end(); ++it)
```

I don't think using the arrow operator is what I intend here.

Comment: An iterator is an abstraction intended to operate very much like a pointer, so in a way `it` is a pointer to a pointer and will need to be dereferenced to get access to the pointer it refers to.

Comment: Is there a reason your `list` contains pointers instead of raw `Event` objects? There can be reasons to do this, but a lot of the time the pointers are unnecessary (especially when you're using a `list` and the nodes of the `list` can be rearranged with zero-copy, zero-move semantics, making the benefits of pointers even smaller) and make things worse in *several* ways.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It was a given header file, but I'm sure there is likely little point to using the pointers. However, there are other functions that have been written based around that format.

Comment: *"I want to iterate through this EventList,"* -- through what `EventList`? You gave is a type definition and stated "not part of a class". Then you mentioned a function, and suddenly there is an object of this type, and somehow we're now in the context of a class (since the `this` pointer is used)? I think you skipped a few too many steps in your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message

> {aka ‘std::__cxx11::list<Event*>*’} (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)

it seems you have a pointer to a list.

In this case the loop can look like

```
for (it = this->el->begin(); it != this->el->end(); ++it){
    cout << (*it)->key << endl;
}
```

Or you could use a range-based for loop like

```
for ( const auto &e : *this->el )
{
    cout << e->key << endl;
}
```

Comment: And then you should get rid of `this->` to make it a little cleaner: `for (it = el->begin(); it != el->end(); ++it)` or `for ( const auto &e : *el )`